# Firefox animation-play-state not updating correctly for pseudo elements

Tags: html, css, firefox, animation, pseudo-element

In this [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wuh5w3cb/) I created, the element `div#load` and its `::before` and `::after` pseudo-elements are all animated. However, if I change the `animation-play-state` of the div to `'paused'`, only the main element stop moving. The pseudo-elements continues their animation until I hover over them in the Inspector. If I change it to `'running'` again, all three would continue the animation.

This is not the case in Google Chrome, where the pseudo-elements stops as they should.

What should I do to fully stop the animation?

HTML:

```
<div id="load"></div>
<input type="button" value="Stop Animation" onclick="load.style.animationPlayState='paused';" />
<input type="button" value="Continue Animation" onclick="load.style.animationPlayState='running';" />
```

CSS:

```
#load {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  margin-left: -16px;
  margin-top: -16px;
  width: 24px;
  height: 24px;
  border: 4px solid transparent;
  border-left: 4px solid rgba(255,0,0,0.5);
  border-radius: 16px;
  -webkit-animation: r 4s linear 0s infinite;
  -moz-animation: r 4s linear 0s infinite;
  animation: r 4s linear 0s infinite;
}
#load::before, #load::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  left: -4px;
  top: -4px;
  width: 24px;
  height: 24px;
  border: 4px solid transparent;
  border-radius: 16px;
  -webkit-animation-play-state: inherit !important;
  -moz-animation-play-state: inherit !important;
  animation-play-state: inherit !important;
}
#load::before {
  border-top: 4px solid rgba(0,0,255,0.5);
  -webkit-animation: r 5s linear 0s infinite;
  -moz-animation: r 5s linear 0s infinite;
  animation: r 5s linear 0s infinite;
}
#load::after {
  border-right: 4px solid rgba(0,255,0,0.5);
  -webkit-animation: r 1600ms linear 0s infinite reverse;
  -moz-animation: r 1600ms linear 0s infinite reverse;
  animation: r 1600ms linear 0s infinite reverse;
}
@-webkit-keyframes r {
  from { transform: rotate(0deg); }
  to { transform: rotate(360deg);}
}
@-moz-keyframes r {
  from { transform: rotate(0deg); }
  to { transform: rotate(360deg);}
}
@keyframes r {
  from { transform: rotate(0deg); }
  to { transform: rotate(360deg);}
}
```

Any help is appreciated :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same issue.

It seems that using a class to change the state works better. Try with this:

CSS:

```
#load.paused { animation-play-state: paused; }
```

or:

```
#load.paused:before,
#load.paused:after { animation-play-state: paused; }
```

(for the sake of readability I didn't include the vendor prefixed properties)

HTML:

```
<div id="load"></div>
<input type="button" value="Stop Animation" onclick="document.getElementById('load').classList.add('paused')" />
<input type="button" value="Continue Animation" onclick="document.getElementById('load').classList.remove('paused')" />
```